# how to replace brackets in url with bracket encoding?

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex pattern that will find and replace brackets in urls to its urls encoding.

For example a base url like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/bla/blabla/abc[1].txt
```

will be turned to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/bla/blabla/abc%5B1%5D.txt
```

can anyone help please?

EDIT1:
i originaly use commons-httpclient to access this kind of urls.
when I use the first URL I get an "escaped absolute path no valid" exception.

I can't use URLENCODER because when  I use it, I get a "host parameter is null" exception.

Comment: You should use an actual URL encoder, not a regex.

Comment: Have you seen the [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class? Does this have to be a `regex`?

Answer (score 2):

The following line should do the trick

```
String s = URLEncoder.encode("http://www.mysite.com/bla/blabla/abc[1].txt", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I'm trying to access this kind of urls with commons-httpclient.
when i use URLEncoder, Http.getClient().executeMethod, I get "host parameter is null" exception.
When I just change the brackets, it works fine. That's why I asked for a regex substitution, just for the brackets.

Comment: Thats probably due to the http:// part being encoded too. You can get rid of it by using 
String s = s.replaceFirst("http://", "");
s = "http://"+s;

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried URLEncoder.encode?

in the java.net.URLEncoder package.

EDIT:

Ok i see...  you cannot pass an entire URL to URLEncoder.  URLEncoder is mostly used to encode query parameters.

try this instead:

```
URI uri = new URI("http", "www.mysite.com", "/bla/blabla/abc[1].txt",null);
    System.out.println(uri.toASCIIString());
```

Comment: Can you post your code?  I don't see why encode would not work

Comment: ?...  read the JavaDoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URI.html for the diffrent constructor of URI class.  basicaly, you pass the protocol, host, path and you have it!

Comment: THANKS. a regex solution  would be mutch appreciated because i use nutch project and it already has a module for normalizing urls by regex. I just need the right regex+ substitution for this task.